# What is $\mathscr{D}_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}$ where $K$ is a number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory

This is just a simple notation question, but I am having trouble unpacking some notation on a standard algebraic number theory problem. This is a homework question, but I am being asked to solve a problem from another university class's problem set, so I am not familiar with the notation that is being used (hence why my notes or my text are unhelpful).

The problem is as follows:

Let $d,d'$ be squarefree integers, let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d},\sqrt{d'})$, and let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$. Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a generator of $\mathscr{D}_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}$ and suppose that $p$ is a prime factor of $a$. Prove that $p\mid 2dd'$. (Hint: First compute the discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d},\sqrt{d'}]$.)

My question is simply: what is $\mathscr{D}_{\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}}$? As in, literally what does this notation mean? Note that I am not asking for any help on the problem itself.

Comment: It is probably [the different ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal).

Comment: Actually [Keith Conrad's notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf) seem to be a better source. He leads up to it well, and does the quadratic fields as an example early on.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your comment; it definitely does indeed appear to be the different ideal. As I explain in my question, my text was unhelpful because this problem was not an exercise found in my text. Indeed, my text (Milne) does not even mention the different ideal.

Comment: Sorry about missing that passage.

Comment: This may be confusing because Milne also has a notation $\mathcal{D}_{B/A}$, but there it is the generalized discriminant.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sorry, I was hoping you could give me a page number for Milne's use of that notation for the generalized discriminant? I was not able to find any mention of generalized discriminant anywhere. Now I am not so sure whether my problem is referring to the generalized discriminant or the different ideal.